# Where is my Win 8.1? Installing dual boot of Win 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on ASUS Vivobook S400CA

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, asus

I am not the most experienced in installing Ubuntu, and I have heard that installing Ubuntu on ASUS Vivobook is problematic. Is anyone here has experience in doing this?

I tried to follow the instructions here - [ubuntu-on-touch-screen-laptop-setting](http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.co.il/2014/06/ubuntu-on-touch-screen-laptop-setting.html).

But at the installation type screen I don't have the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1, I only have the following options:

- Erase disk and install Ubuntu
- Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security
- Use LVM with new Ubuntu installation
- Something else

What should I do?

Comment: I have two hard drives on this laptop: SanDisk SSD U100 24GB, and a ST500LT012-9WS142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** I'm re-writing this answer to match the edited question **Edit**

This issue is caused by UEFI Boot. The Unified Extensible Firmware Interface ([UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)) (pronounced as an initialism U-E-F-I or like "unify" without the n)[a] is a specification that defines a software interface between an operating system and platform firmware. UEFI is meant to replace the Basic Input/Output System (BIOS) firmware interface, originally present in all IBM PC-compatible personal computers. In practice, most UEFI firmware images provide legacy support for BIOS services. UEFI can support remote diagnostics and repair of computers, even without another operating system

Education out of the way, the steps to work around this issue are long, but not overly painful. Due to their length, I am going to very briefly summarize them here:

1) Backup Windows

2) Create your Installation Media

3) Shrink your windows partition

4) Turn off Secure Boot

5) Install Ubuntu

The guide has a lot of instructions here that I didn't need the last time Installed. So before I give you the link to follow, here's my caveat: If the installer gives you the option of installing alongside Windows, use that instead of this guide. If you still don't see it, then follow the guide.

All that said, here is the link: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

I also recommend logging into the Ubuntu IRC channel during the install. If you have any questions, you can connect right with the community rather than having to wait for replies here. Should they walk you through different steps, please let us know what worked for you so that we can clean up this question.

~ Geary

Comment: Looking at the link, it is exactly the one he tried to follow.

Comment: I tried to follow the link's instructions, but I encountered a puzzlement during the installation - at the Installation type screen I didn't have the choice of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. What could be the problem?

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. Windows 8+ uses something called UEFI Boot, which is a secure infrastructure designed to prevent various malware and viruses from inserting themselves into the Windows Kernel. That said, I'm sure that you're more interested in how to solve the issue than what it is. The link below is a rather exhaustive guide on how to accomplish this: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: Thank you Geary for your help so far. I need to organize an external hard drive to backup my files before the procedure you addressed me to. But before I start with it I am considering of choosing to install only Ubuntu, getting rid of the Windows on this laptop. What worries me in trying this option is that the Ubuntu installation does not "see" the Windows, and the question is whether it will succeed in taking control over the computer, without Windows left overs interfering..

Comment: If you instruct Ubuntu to use the entire drive, then it doesn't matter if the installer sees it or not. It simply overwrites the entire drive

Comment: I just followed the instruction at the guide that you've sent me and the installation went perfectly fine, I didn't need even to do the boot repair procedure. One last question - can I now turn back on the 'fast boot' option in Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Im aure one of the wiser heads will correct me should I be wrong, but it has to do with how windows interacts with the boot loader

Answer (score 0):

> But at the installation type screen I don't have the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1, I only have the following options:
>
> - Erase disk and install Ubuntu
> - […]
> - Something else

This isn't enough information to draw a conclusion. If you can run GParted and it detects the partition table and individual partitions, then this is an issue with the Ubuntu installer and you should use [manual partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/a/521195/40581) ("something else").

If existing partitions are not detected there might be another issue, be sure to boot the installation media in UEFI mode on UEFI machines (I recommend [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/395879/40581)). If partitions are still not getting detected disable secure boot (this shouldn't be necessary as 14.04 installed just fine in my tests with secure boot enabled).